# Using scons to build on Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: c++, macos, sdl, osx-mavericks, scons

I've been trying to compile The Powder Toy (written in C++) from the source code using `scons` and SDL. I will admit that I am not very experienced with compiling/building, but this looks like it should be possible.

I am running on Mac OSX 10.9 (Mavericks); which has caused issues with SDL. However, I found a fix for this and I now have XCode, XQuartz, Command line tools, scons and SDL successfully installed. However, if I `cd` into the source directory and run `scons --macosx --release --sse2 --nofft`
I get the error

```
src/PowderToySDL.cpp:6:10: fatal error:
'SDL.h' file not found #include "SDL.h"
                                 ^
```

So clearly, the folder that includes SDL.h (./SDL/include) is not being found. I tried adding the tag

`--sdl-dir="~/Desktop/Programming/SDL-1.2.15/include"`

to the call to `scons,` however the same error persisted. I checked the directory `./SDL/include`, and all of the correct files were there; however scons does not seem to be referencing them.

Full output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/src/PowderToySDL.o -c -w -std=c++98 -fkeep-inline-functions -O3 -ftree-vectorize -funsafe-math-optimizations -ffast-math -fomit-frame-pointer -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/Lua.framework/Headers -m32 -msse2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DUSE_STDINT -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DLUACONSOLE -DUSE_SDL -DMACOSX -DSTABLE -DX86 -DX86_SSE2 -Ibuild/src -Isrc -Ibuild/data -Idata -Ibuild/generated -Igenerated src/PowderToySDL.cpp
src/PowderToySDL.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
#include "SDL.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
scons: *** [build/src/PowderToySDL.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Build script: (SConstruct)

```
AddOption('--builddir',dest="builddir",default="build",help="Directory to build to.")
SConscript('SConscript', variant_dir=GetOption('builddir'), duplicate=0)
```

SConscript

```
# ============
# SCons script
# ============

# the purpose of this script is to run a build of tpt from start to finish, including dependency checks.

# .. contents :: Table of Contents

# ============
# requirements
# ============

# stdlib
# ======

import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time

# 3rd party
# =========

# nothing besides scons.

# =================
# long commandlines
# =================

# .. : Fix for long command line - http://scons.org/wiki/LongCmdLinesOnWin32

# because of an implementation detail commandlines are limited to 10000 characters on windows using mingw. the following fix was copied from
# http://scons.org/wiki/LongCmdLinesOnWin32 and circumvents this issue.

class ourSpawn:
    def ourspawn(self, sh, escape, cmd, args, env):
        newargs = ' '.join(args[1:])
        cmdline = cmd + " " + newargs
        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo, shell = False, env = env)
        data, err = proc.communicate()
        rv = proc.wait()
        if rv:
            print "====="
            print err
            print "====="
        return rv

def SetupSpawn( env ):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        buf = ourSpawn()
        buf.ourenv = env
        env['SPAWN'] = buf.ourspawn

# ===================
# commandline options
# ===================

# the following defines all optional commandlines

AddOption('--opengl',dest="opengl",action='store_true',default=False,help="Build with OpenGL interface support.")
AddOption('--opengl-renderer',dest="opengl-renderer",action='store_true',default=False,help="Build with OpenGL renderer support. (requires --opengl)")
AddOption('--renderer',dest="renderer",action='store_true',default=False,help="Save renderer")
AddOption('--64bit',dest="_64bit",action='store_true',default=False,help="64-bit platform target")
AddOption('--static',dest="static",action="store_true",default=False,help="Static linking, reduces external library dependancies but increased file size")
AddOption('--pthreadw32-static',dest="ptw32-static",action="store_true",default=False,help="Use PTW32_STATIC_LIB for pthreadw32 headers")
AddOption('--python-ver',dest="pythonver",default=False,help="Python version to use for generator.py")
AddOption('--release',dest="release",action='store_true',default=False,help="Enable optimisations (Will slow down compiling)")
AddOption('--lua-dir',dest="lua-dir",default=False,help="Directory for lua includes")
AddOption('--sdl-dir',dest="sdl-dir",default=False,help="Directory for SDL includes")
AddOption('--tool',dest="toolprefix",default=False,help="Prefix")
AddOption('--sse',dest="sse",action='store_true',default=False,help="Enable SSE optimisations")
AddOption('--sse2',dest="sse2",action='store_true',default=False,help="Enable SSE2 optimisations")
AddOption('--sse3',dest="sse3",action='store_true',default=False,help="Enable SSE3 optimisations")
AddOption('--x86',dest="x86",action='store_true',default=True,help="Target Intel x86 platform")
AddOption('--nofft',dest="nofft", action='store_true',default=False,help="Do not use fftw3f for gravity.")
AddOption('--nolua',dest="nolua", action='store_true',default=False,help="Disable all lua scripting features.")

AddOption('--debugging', dest="debug", action="store_true", default=False, help="Enable debug options")
AddOption('--beta',dest="beta",action='store_true',default=False,help="Beta build.")
AddOption('--save-version',dest="save-version",default=False,help="Save version.")
AddOption('--minor-version',dest="minor-version",default=False,help="Minor version.")
AddOption('--build-number',dest="build-number",default=False,help="Build number.")
AddOption('--snapshot',dest="snapshot",action='store_true',default=False,help="Snapshot build.")
AddOption('--snapshot-id',dest="snapshot-id",default=False,help="Snapshot build ID.")
AddOption('--stable',dest="stable",default=True,help="Non snapshot build")
AddOption('--aao', dest="everythingAtOnce", action='store_true', default=False, help="Compile the whole game without generating intermediate objects (very slow), enable this when using compilers like clang or mscc that don't support -fkeep-inline-functions")

AddOption('--fullclean',dest="justwork",action='store_true',default=False,help="for when nothing else works. Deletes all sconscript temporary files.") 
AddOption('--copy-env',dest="copy_env",action='store_true',default=False,help="copy some common enviroment variables from the parent enviroment.") 

# using one of these commandline options is compulsory

AddOption('--win',dest="win",action='store_true',default=False,help="Windows platform target.")
AddOption('--lin',dest="lin",action='store_true',default=False,help="Linux platform target")
AddOption('--macosx',dest="macosx",action='store_true',default=False,help="Mac OS X platform target")
AddOption('--rpi',dest="rpi",action='store_true',default=False,help="Raspbain platform target")

# ============
# main program
# ============

# the gist of the compiling rules are defined here


if(GetOption("justwork")):
    import shutil
    try:
        shutil.rmtree("../.sconf_temp/")
    except:
        print "couldn't remove .sconf_temp"
    try:
        os.remove("../.sconsign.dblite")
    except:
        print "couldn't remove .sconsign.dblite"

# platform selection
# ==================

# generic platform settings
# +++++++++++++++++++++++++

# check if a platform is specified.
# .. : TODO: make it suggest commandline options if it isn't

if((not GetOption('lin')) and (not GetOption('win')) and (not GetOption('rpi')) and (not GetOption('macosx'))):
    print "You must specify a platform to target"
    raise SystemExit(1)

# windows specific platform settings
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

# if the platform is windows switch to a mingw toolset, use the default otherwise

if(GetOption('win')):
    env = Environment(tools = ['mingw'], ENV = os.environ)
else:
    env = Environment(tools = ['default'], ENV = os.environ)

if(GetOption("copy_env")):
    lstvar=["CC","CXX","LD","CFLAGS","LIBPATH"]
    print "WARNING: enviroment copying enabled. changes in the enviroment can easily break the build process."
    for var in lstvar:
        if var in os.environ:
            env[var]=os.environ[var]
            print "WARNING: copying enviroment variable {}={!r}".format(var,os.environ[var])

# macosx specific platform settings
# +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

# if we're not on MACOSX check for headers etc

if not GetOption("macosx"):
    conf = Configure(env)

# if sdl-dir is set check if we can find the sdl header there, if we can't just pass the header path to the compiler.

    if(GetOption("sdl-dir")):
        if not conf.CheckCHeader(GetOption("sdl-dir") + '/SDL.h'):
            print "sdl headers not found or not installed"
            raise SystemExit(1)
        else:
            env.Append(CPPPATH=[GetOption("sdl-dir")])
    else:

# otherwise try to parse the pkg config for sdl and grab the correct flags from there.

        try:
            env.ParseConfig('sdl-config --cflags')
            env.ParseConfig('sdl-config --libs')
        except:
            if not conf.CheckLib("SDL"):
                print "libSDL not found or not installed"
                raise SystemExit(1)


# if lua is enabled try to parse the lua pgk-config, or the lua-dir option if given

    if not GetOption("nolua"):
        if(GetOption("lua-dir")):
            if not conf.CheckCHeader(GetOption("lua-dir") + '/lua.h'):
                print "lua5.1 headers not found or not installed"
                raise SystemExit(1)
            else:
                env.Append(CPPPATH=[GetOption("lua-dir")])
        try:
            env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --cflags lua5.1')
            env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --libs lua5.1')
        except:
            #Check for Lua lib
            if not conf.CheckLib('lua5.1') and not conf.CheckLib('lua-5.1') and not conf.CheckLib('lua51') and not conf.CheckLib('lua'):
                print "liblua5.1 not found or not installed"
                raise SystemExit(1)

# if fft is enabled try to parse its config, fail otherwise.

    if not GetOption('nofft'):
        # Check for FFT lib
        if not conf.CheckLib('fftw3f') and not conf.CheckLib('fftw3f-3'):
            print "libfftw3f not found or not installed"
            raise SystemExit(1)

# try to autodetect some libraries, fail otherwise

    #Check for Bzip lib
    if not conf.CheckLib('bz2'):
        print "libbz2 not found or not installed"
        raise SystemExit(1)

    #Check for zlib
    if not conf.CheckLib('z'):
        print "libz not found or not installed"
        raise SystemExit(1)

    if not conf.CheckCHeader("bzlib.h"):
        print "bzip2 headers not found"
        raise SystemExit(1)

# finish the configuration

    env = conf.Finish();
else:

# if we ARE on macosx add the libraries to LIBS
# .. : seems like we're terrible at mac support? what gives?

    env.Append(LIBS=['z', 'bz2'])
    if not GetOption('nofft'):
        env.Append(LIBS=['fftw3f'])

# enviroment setup
# ================

# add the correct compiler flags.

# generic enviroment settings
# +++++++++++++++++++++++++++

# check if a tool prefix is set, and if it is select the propper tools for building.
# .. : TODO someone explain wtf this actually does

if GetOption("toolprefix"):
    env['CC'] = GetOption("toolprefix")+env['CC']
    env['CXX'] = GetOption("toolprefix")+env['CXX']
    if GetOption('win'):
        env['RC'] = GetOption("toolprefix")+env['RC']

# make sure the compiler can find the source data and generated files. enable warnings, set C++ flavor, and keep inline functions

env.Append(CPPPATH=['src/', 'data/', 'generated/'])
env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-w', '-std=c++98', '-fkeep-inline-functions'])
env.Append(LIBS=['pthread', 'm'])
env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["_GNU_SOURCE", "USE_STDINT", "_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L"])

# check all enabled libs, and add a define if they are enabled.

if not GetOption('nofft'):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["GRAVFFT"])
if not GetOption('nolua'):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["LUACONSOLE"])

# check if we need to use PTW32_STATIC_LIB for pthreadw32 headers, won't compile statically without this

if GetOption("ptw32-static"):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['PTW32_STATIC_LIB']);

# check if we need to do static linking.

if(GetOption('static')):
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-static-libgcc'])

# check if we need to compile the save renderer. add a define accordingly. compile the game by default.

if(GetOption('renderer')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['RENDERER'])
else:
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["USE_SDL"])

# apply optimisations if it's a release build

if(GetOption('release')):
    if GetOption('macosx'):
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-O3', '-ftree-vectorize', '-funsafe-math-optimizations', '-ffast-math', '-fomit-frame-pointer'])
    else:
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-O3', '-ftree-vectorize', '-funsafe-math-optimizations', '-ffast-math', '-fomit-frame-pointer', '-funsafe-loop-optimizations', '-Wunsafe-loop-optimizations'])

# rpi specific enviroment settings
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

# check if we're compiling for raspberry pi, if we are include rpi specific libraries and defines.

if(GetOption('rpi')):
        if(GetOption('opengl')):
                env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --libs glew gl glu')
        openGLLibs = ['GL']
        env.Append(LIBS=['X11', 'rt'])
        env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["LIN"])


# windows specific enviroment settings
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

# check if we're compiling for windows, if we are include windows specific libraries and defines.

if(GetOption('win')):
    openGLLibs = ['opengl32', 'glew32']
    env.Prepend(LIBS=['mingw32', 'ws2_32', 'SDLmain', 'SDL'])
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-std=gnu++98'])
    env.Append(LIBS=['winmm', 'gdi32'])
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["WIN"])
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-mwindows'])
    if(GetOption('_64bit')):
        env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['__CRT__NO_INLINE'])
        env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-Wl,--stack=16777216'])

# linux specific enviroment settings
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

# check if we're compiling for linux, if we are include linux specific libraries and defines.

if(GetOption('lin')):
    if(GetOption('opengl')):
        env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --libs glew gl glu')
    openGLLibs = ['GL']
    env.Append(LIBS=['X11', 'rt'])
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["LIN"])
    if GetOption('_64bit'):
        env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-m64'])
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-m64'])
    else:
        env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-m32'])
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-m32'])

# macosx specific enviroment settings
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

# check if we're compiling for macosx, if we are include macosx specific libraries and defines.

if(GetOption('macosx')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["MACOSX"])
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers'])
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-I/Library/Frameworks/Lua.framework/Headers'])
    if not GetOption('nofft'):
        env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-lfftw3f'])
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-framework'])
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['SDL'])
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-framework'])
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['Lua'])
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-framework']);
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['Cocoa'])
    #env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-framework SDL'])
    #env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-framework Lua'])
    #env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-framework Cocoa'])
    if GetOption('_64bit'):
        env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-m64'])
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-m64'])
    else:
        env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-m32'])
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-m32'])

# defines
# =======

# A lot of commandline flags translate directly into defines. those flags follow:

if GetOption('_64bit'):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["_64BIT"])

if(GetOption('beta')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES='BETA')

if(not GetOption('snapshot') and not GetOption('beta') and not GetOption('release') and not GetOption('stable')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES='SNAPSHOT_ID=0')
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES='SNAPSHOT')
elif(GetOption('snapshot') or GetOption('snapshot-id')):
    if(GetOption('snapshot-id')):
        env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['SNAPSHOT_ID=' + GetOption('snapshot-id')])
    else:
        env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['SNAPSHOT_ID=' + str(int(time.time()))])
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES='SNAPSHOT')
elif(GetOption('stable')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES='STABLE')

if(GetOption('save-version')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['SAVE_VERSION=' + GetOption('save-version')])

if(GetOption('minor-version')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['MINOR_VERSION=' + GetOption('minor-version')])

if(GetOption('build-number')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['BUILD_NUM=' + GetOption('build-number')])

if(GetOption('x86')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES='X86')

if(GetOption('debug')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES='DEBUG')
    env.Append(CCFLAGS='-g')

if(GetOption('sse')):
    env.Append(CCFLAGS='-msse')
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES='X86_SSE')

if(GetOption('sse2')):
    env.Append(CCFLAGS='-msse2')
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES='X86_SSE2')

if(GetOption('sse3')):
    env.Append(CCFLAGS='-msse3')
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES='X86_SSE3')

if(GetOption('opengl')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["OGLI", "PIX32OGL"])
    env.Append(LIBS=openGLLibs)

if(GetOption('opengl') and GetOption('opengl-renderer')):
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["OGLR"])
elif(GetOption('opengl-renderer')):
    print "opengl-renderer requires opengl"
    raise SystemExit(1)

# compiling
# =========

# sources
# +++++++

# find all source files

# generic sources
# ---------------
sources=Glob("src/*.cpp")

sources+=Glob("src/*/*.cpp")
sources+=Glob("src/gui/*/*.cpp")
sources+=Glob("src/simulation/elements/*.cpp")
sources+=Glob("src/simulation/tools/*.cpp")
sources+=Glob("src/client/requestbroker/*.cpp")
if not GetOption('nolua'):
    sources+=Glob("src/socket/*.c")

# windows specific sources
# ------------------------

if(GetOption('win')):
    sources += env.RES('resources/powder-res.rc')
    sources = filter(lambda source: not 'src\\simulation\\Gravity.cpp' in str(source), sources)
    sources = filter(lambda source: not 'src/simulation/Gravity.cpp' in str(source), sources)

# macosx specific sources
# -----------------------

if(GetOption('macosx')):
    sources +=["SDLMain.m"]

# apply `long commandlines`_ fix
# ==============================

# apply the commandline fix

SetupSpawn(env)

# find proper executable name
# ===========================

# use some settings to detect what name to use for the executable

programName = "powder"

if(GetOption('renderer')):
    programName = "render"

if(GetOption('win')):
    if(GetOption('renderer')):
        programName = "Render"
    else:
        programName = "Powder"

if(GetOption('_64bit')):
    programName += "64"

if(not (GetOption('sse2') or GetOption('sse3'))):
    programName += "-legacy"

if(GetOption('macosx')):
    programName += "-x"

if(GetOption('win')):
    programName += ".exe"


# detect python executable name
# =============================

# detect the executable name for python so we can run some generator scripts

if(GetOption('pythonver')):
    pythonVer = GetOption('pythonver')
elif(GetOption('lin')):
    pythonVer = "python2"
else:
    pythonVer = "python"

# Extra compiler flag to fix stack alignment
# When Windows creates the gravity calculation thread, it has 4 byte stack alignment
# But we need 16 byte alignment so that SSE instructions in FFTW work without crashing
if(GetOption('win')):
   envCopy = env.Clone()
   envCopy.Append(CCFLAGS=['-mstackrealign'])
   #envCopy.Append(CCFLAGS=['-mincoming-stack-boundary=2'])
   sources+=envCopy.Object('src/simulation/Gravity.cpp')

# run generator commands
# ======================

env.Command(['generated/ElementClasses.cpp', 'generated/ElementClasses.h'], Glob('src/simulation/elements/*.cpp'), pythonVer + " generator.py elements $TARGETS $SOURCES")
sources+=Glob("generated/ElementClasses.cpp")

env.Command(['generated/ToolClasses.cpp', 'generated/ToolClasses.h'], Glob('src/simulation/tools/*.cpp'), pythonVer + " generator.py tools $TARGETS $SOURCES")
sources+=Glob("generated/ToolClasses.cpp")

# final settings
# ==============

# make a MD5 checksum decide wether or not a file changed. we had some problems with using the modification date for this purpose.

env.Decider('MD5')

# set a defaukt target

t=env.Program(target=programName, source=sources)
Default(t)
```

Comment: Can we see the complete compilation output, and the related build scripts, please. The problem is that the include path (-I compiler flags) is not correctly configured.

Comment: @Brady hopefully that was the correct file. Added.

Comment: Actually, the SConstruct would have been better. What you need to do is configure the include paths via the CPPPATH construction variable. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've attached the SConscript for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is set the include path via the [CPPPATH construction variable](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/a4774.html), as follows:

```
# Not sure if SCons will recognize the tilde (~), so
# you may have to put the complete absolute path
env.Append(CPPPATH='~/Desktop/Programming/SDL-1.2.15/include')

# Not sure if it should be ./SDL/include instead, but if more
# than one dir needs to be added, just use a list
# env.Append(CPPPATH=['~/Desktop/Programming/SDL-1.2.15/include', './SDL/include'])
```

Comment: I tried adding it into SConfig like so: `env.Append(CPPPATH=['src/', 'data/', 'generated/', 'Users/alaricsanders/Desktop/Programming/SDL-1.2.15/include'])` but it gave me the same error.

Comment: @catalogue_number now that you've added those include paths, take a look at the compilation output and check that the paths are correct (I suspect you need a '/' before 'Users'). If the dir is inside the project dir, then it will be relative to the root SConstruct dir.

Comment: Whoops, typo. That fix worked, but now it can't find lua.h; and I don't know where this file is even supposed to be. I just know that I don't have the file; I'll contact the developers for help.

Comment: @catalogue_number, good luck. I know on Linux you can query the installed packages and find where installed files are, but not sure about MacOs. Mac is basically Linux too, so you should be able to do it.

Comment: I've tried running with the `--nolua` flag (removes the need for lua dependencies), but now the compiler is finding an error in one of the source files. It seems the function is not recognising the function `strcasecmp()` as a function, throwing out an undeclared identifier error. It seems that string.h isn't being included in this scope.